# Using Colormaps with a threshold line

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I am trying to use colormaps to show my data. I went through this list:
https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html

I found out that RdBu and Seismic data maps are suitable for what I want to achieve with my bar chart. How can I incorporate them into my code?

This is the code that I've been using:

```
threshold = 40000
plt.axhline(y = threshold, linewidth=1, color = 'black')


#Plot bar chart and errorbars
#plt.cla()
#data_color = [x / max(y) for x in y]
my_color = []

for k in range(0, len(xvals)):
    if (smax[k] < threshold):
        my_color.append('blue')
    elif (smax[k] > threshold) & (smin[k] < threshold):
        my_color.append('grey')
    else:
        my_color.append('red')

plt.bar(xvals, y, width = 1.0, tick_label = xvals, color = my_color)
plt.errorbar(xvals, y, yerr = yerr1, linestyle = '', capsize = 10, color = 'black')
```

This is the output I'm getting:
[Manually added colours. Would like them to be taken from RdBu/ Seismic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54rd0.png)

Comment: Where should you get the blue column? If you increase the number of your bars you would get blue columns too. I am not able to understand what is the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give an explanation of what you are doing that will probably help you debug your problem.

#### np.linespace

`np.linspace(.1, .9, 10)` returns 10 evenly spaced numbers over 0.1 - 0.9 interval:
`[0.1 0.18888889 0.27777778 0.36666667 0.45555556 0.544444440.63333333 0.72222222 0.81111111 0.9]`

---

#### cm.seismic

Then you input the above array on `cm.seismic`. This will give a color value to each point of the `linspace` starting from blue to red.
So by calling `cm.seismic(np.linspace(.1, .9, 10))` you get this color maping:

```
Red         Green      Blue       Alpha (Opacity)
[0.         0.         0.5745098  1.        ]
[0.         0.         0.82705882 1.        ]
[0.11372549 0.11372549 1.         1.        ]
[0.45882353 0.45882353 1.         1.        ]
[0.81960784 0.81960784 1.         1.        ]
[1.         0.81960784 0.81960784 1.        ]
[1.         0.45882353 0.45882353 1.        ]
[1.         0.11372549 0.11372549 1.        ]
[0.87647059 0.         0.         1.        ]
[0.69607843 0.         0.         1.        ]
```

So the first point of your data will get the first row of the above array as its color value and so forth.

---

#### plt.bar

In your case you plot 4 data points (bars). So the 1st bar will have as its color the first row of the color map (`0. 0. 0.5745098 1.`) which is dark blue.
Having 4 bars on your data you will only use the first 4 rows of your color map never reaching the red colors.

The code I used to reproduce your question:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xvals = [0,1,2,3]
y = np.array([30000,35000,40000,50000])
cmap=plt.get_cmap("seismic")
print(np.linspace(.1, .9, 10))
my_colors = cmap(np.linspace(.1, .9, 10))
print(my_colors)
plt.bar(xvals, y, width = 1.0, tick_label = xvals, color=my_colors)

plt.show()
```

**Finally** if you are trying to achieve a specific output edit your question and I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Mike. This was a subpart of what I was trying to achieve. I think what you are saying is correct - if I had more bars, I would get the entire range of blue and red. What I am trying to do is to have a threshold line and depending on whether my bars are above or below the threshold; color them in the RdBu colormap scheme. I will update my question once I'm done trying my code out for the same.

Comment: I just needed to change np.linspace(.1, .9, 10) to np.linspace(.1, .9, 4) for it to give me the desired color scheme to 4 bars. Thanks Mike. Should have figured this out earlier.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. If my answer helped you feel free to upvote it or accept it as an answer for users that may stumble on similar problems.

Comment: I had already upvoted it, but don't have enough reputation for it to reflect on the answer. I accepted it as an answer now. Thanks again.